# Merge array of objects preserving some key-values php

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Consider the following two arrays:

```
[
{
    id: jhz,
    name: 'John',
    eyes: 'Green',
    description: 'Cool guy',
},
{
    id: mbe,
    name: 'Mary',
    brand: 'M&B',
    text: 'Something',  
}
]
```

```
[
{
    id: jhz,
    name: 'John',
    eyes: '',
},
{
    id: mbe,
    name: 'Mary',
},
{
    id: 'beh',
    name: 'Bernard',
}
]
```

First array may have any kind of key value pairs, but it will always have the key `id` and `name`. I want to merge the two arrays by taking `id` and `name` into account and **preserving them**, while merging everything else and replacing them with **data from the first array** if any keys duplicate.

Also tricky part - the merged array needs to follow **the order of the second array.**

So in this example the result I'm looking for is:

```
[
{
    id: jhz,
    name: 'John',
    eyes: 'Green',
    description: 'Cool guy',
},
{
    id: mbe,
    name: 'Mary',
    brand: 'M&B',
    text: 'Something',  
},
{
    id: 'beh',
    name: 'Bernard',
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this using `Array.map`

```js
const data1 = [{
    id: 'jhz',
    name: 'John',
    eyes: 'Green',
    description: 'Cool guy',
  },
  {
    id: 'mbe',
    name: 'Mary',
    brand: 'M&B',
    text: 'Something',
  }
]


const data2 = [{
    id: 'jhz',
    name: 'John',
    eyes: '',
  },
  {
    id: 'mbe',
    name: 'Mary',
  },
  {
    id: 'beh',
    name: 'Bernard',
  }
]

const result = data2.map(d => ({...d, ...(data1.find(d1 => d1.id === d.id && d1.name === d.name) || {})}))

console.log(result)
```